# How can a primitive float value be -0.0? What does that mean?

Tags: java, floating-point

How come a primitive float value can be -0.0? What does that mean?
Can I cancel that feature?

When I have:

```
  float fl;
```

Then `fl == -0.0` returns `true` and so does `fl == 0`. But when I print it, it prints `-0.0`.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Because Java uses the [IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) which defines `-0.0` and when it should be used.

> The smallest number representable has no 1 bit in the subnormal significand and is called the positive or *negative zero* as determined by the sign. It actually **represents a rounding to zero of numbers in the range between zero and the smallest representable non-zero number of the same sign**, which is why it has a sign, and why its reciprocal +Inf or -Inf also has a sign.

You can get around your specific problem by adding `0.0`

e.g.

```
Double.toString(value + 0.0);
```

See: [Java Floating-Point Number Intricacies](https://web.archive.org/web/20050921090806/http://www.concentric.net/~Ttwang/tech/javafloat.htm)

> **Operations Involving Negative Zero**
>    ...
>    (-0.0) + 0.0  ->  0.0

-

> "-0.0" is produced when a floating-point operation results in a negative floating-point number so close to 0 that it cannot be represented normally.

Answer (score 21):

> how come a primitive float value can be -0.0?

floating point numbers are stored in memory using the [IEEE 754 standard](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html) meaning that there could be rounding errors. You could never be able to store a floating point number of infinite precision with finite resources.

You should never test if a floating point number == to some other, i.e. never write code like this:

```
if (a == b)
```

where `a` and `b` are floats. Due to rounding errors those two numbers might be stored as different values in memory.

You should define a precision you want to work with:

```
private final static double EPSILON = 0.00001;
```

and then test against the precision you need

```
if (Math.abs(a - b) < epsilon)
```

So in your case if you want to test that a floating point number *equals to zero* in the given precision:

```
if (Math.abs(a) < epsilon)
```

And if you want to format the numbers when outputting them in the GUI you may take a look at the [following article](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) and the [NumberFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class.

Comment: Thanks. I need to print the number in my gui, so I sometimes get -0.0 and sometimes get 0.0. I want to never present -0.0. suggestion?

Comment: @user450602, take a look at the following article for formatting: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 11):

The floating point type in Java is described in the JLS: [4.2.3 Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3).

It talks about these special values:

> (...) Each of the four value sets includes not only the finite nonzero values that are ascribed to it above, but also NaN values and the four values **positive zero, negative zero**, positive infinity, and negative infinity. (...)

And has some important notes about them:

> Positive zero and negative zero compare equal; thus the result of the expression 0.0==-0.0 is true and the result of 0.0>-0.0 is false. But other operations can distinguish positive and negative zero; for example, 1.0/0.0 has the value positive infinity, while the value of 1.0/-0.0 is negative infinity.

You can't "cancel" that feature, it's part of how the floats work.

For more about negative zero, have a look at the [Signed zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) Wikipedia entry.

If you want to check what "kind" of zero you have, you can use the fact that:

```
(new Float(0.0)).equals(new Float(-0.0))
```

is `false` (but indeed, `0.0 == -0.0`).

Have a look here for more of this: [Java Floating-Point Number Intricacies](http://www.acisd.org/campus/rfhs/cs/lessonsAndLabsWebPage0708/.%5Cjavafloat.html).

Answer (score 5):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero)

> The IEEE 754 standard for floating point arithmetic (presently used by
>   most computers and programming languages that support floating point
>   numbers) requires both +0 and −0. The zeroes can be considered as a
>   variant of the extended real number line such that 1/−0 = −∞ and 1/+0
>   = +∞, division by zero is only undefined for ±0/±0 and ±∞/±∞.

I don't think you can or need to cancel that feature. You must not compare floating point numbers with == because of precision errors anyway.

Answer (score 4):

A good article on how float point numbers are managed in java / computers.
http://www.artima.com/underthehood/floating.html

btw: it is real pain in computers when 2.0 - 1.0 could produce 0.999999999999 that is not equal to1.0 :). That can be especially easy stumbled upon in javascript form validations.