# why does Float static compare not require an epsilon value?

Tags: java, floating-point, comparison, epsilon

Upon checking Float.compare(f1,f2)  I found that it compares f1f2
and returns -1,0,1.

Then it returns -1,0,1 if the values are -0.0, 0.0 or NAN.
What does that mean  -0.0?

I would have expected something like

```
 return (Math.abs(f1 - f2) - 0.001f) > 0)
```

where 0.001 is a given epsilon value.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-0.0` is the [**negative zero**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero), as specified by the [IEEE 754 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

If you're curious about how such a value might arise, the following article does a good job of explaining it: http://www.savrola.com/resources/negative_zero.html

As to not taking an epsilon value, this is how `Float.compare` is designed work (it's an exact comparison, not an approximate one). There's nothing to stop you from having another comparison function that *does* take an epsilon and *does* perform an approximate comparison.

Both exact and approximate comparisons of floating-point numbers have their uses.

As to your actual code, it suffers from a number of issues:

1. it isn't a three-way comparison like `Float.compare`;
2. it doesn't handle `NaN`s;
3. it is generally better to specify the epsilon as a relative value, not as an absolute one, so that it scales with `f1` and `f2` (see [this article](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm) for a discussion).

My point here isn't to criticise your code but to show that writing good floating-point code is harder than it first looks.

Comment: but as As I understan floats cannot be compared with == due to rounding errors . when we do floattobits() (inside the original float.copare - doenst it do sort of string compare with the two results?

Comment: @user450602: Both exact and approximate comparisons of floating-point numbers have their uses. It all depends on what you're doing.

Comment: Non taken. anyhow, regarding No.3 and the relative epsilon. I think I didnt explained my question well. I would have thought that Float.compare be a better function if it took (f1,f2,epsilon) as parameters. the rounding errors (which I have learnt about here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724031/how-can-a-primitive-float-value-be-0-0-what-does-that-mean would be avoided better ) . dont you think?

Comment: @user450602: see http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm for a discussion of absolute vs relative error

Answer (score 3):

Floating point arithmetic is tricky. [This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0114/) throws some light on the basics.

-0 is [signed zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero):

> In ordinary arithmetic, −0 = +0 = 0. However, in computing, some
>   number representations allow for the existence of two zeros, often
>   denoted by −0 (negative zero) and +0 (positive zero).
>   [...]
>   The IEEE 754 standard for floating point arithmetic (presently used by
>   most computers and programming languages that support floating point
>   numbers) requires both +0 and −0. The zeroes can be considered as a
>   variant of the extended real number line such that 1/−0 = −∞ and 1/+0
>   = +∞, division by zero is only undefined for ±0/±0 and ±∞/±∞.