# Double value zero multiplication issue

Tags: java

I have following code:

```
    Map<String, Double> finalAmountMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    Double test = 0d;
    finalAmountMap.put("chargeAmount",(-1*test));
    System.out.println(finalAmountMap);
```

**Output** : `{1=-0.0}`

If anything is multiplied with zero results in zero, but java `Double` multiplication of `-1` with `0`  is resulting in  `-0.0`.

*Details : Java version : 1.7.0_21 , Windows 32 bits*

Due to this behavior northbound system rejecting values as -0.0 is not correct mathematical term.

**Is it Java bug?**

Comment: Perhaps this can shed some light... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724031/how-can-a-primitive-float-value-be-0-0-what-does-that-mean

Comment: What is 'northbound system'?

Comment: "is it java bug?" - No.