# Why does Java evaluate 0/-1 and 0.0/-1 differently?

Tags: java, numbers

I tried the following code:

```
System.out.println(0 / 1);
System.out.println(0 / -1);
System.out.println(0.0 / 1.0);
System.out.println(0.0 / -1.0);
```

And the result is:

```
0
0
0.0
-0.0
```

Why does the code evaluate to -0.0 when the divisor is a negative double?How can I get rid of the negative sign?

Comment: you should read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8153449/4341456

Comment: Nothing to do with math 'imprecision' here - the linked guide entry is misleading. Simply, IEEE-754 (the form of representing *floating point values*) has the concept of a *negative zero* (as linked) which is being observed. The difference in *integer division* vs *floating point division* is what changes the result: there is *no -0 integer* value, but there *is a -0.0 floating point* value.

Comment: Also, note that although the negative concept/sign is present (and shown when converted to a string) there is the special property that `0.0 == (0.0 / -1.0)`.