# Why HashSet differentiates 0.0 and -0.0

Tags: java, floating-point, hashset

When I tried this:

```
HashSet<Double> set = new HashSet<>();
Double d1 = new Double(0);
Double d2 = new Double(0);
Double d3 = new Double(-0);
set.add(d1);
System.out.println(set.contains(d2));
System.out.println(set.contains(d3));
```

The output was what I expected:

```
true
true
```

But when I tried:

```
HashSet<Double> set = new HashSet<>();
Double d1 = new Double(0.0);
Double d2 = new Double(0.0);
Double d3 = new Double(-0.0);
set.add(d1);
System.out.println(set.contains(d2));
System.out.println(set.contains(d3));
```

or

```
set.add(Double.valueOf(d1));
System.out.println(set.contains(Double.valueOf(d2)));
System.out.println(set.contains(Double.valueOf(d3)));
```

To my surprise, the output was:

```
true
false
```

Why this happened? How do I make HashSet treat (0.0) and (-0.0) the same?
Is there a better way than `if(num == -0.0) num = 0.0;`?

Comment: Try with `Double.valueOf()` instead of `new Double()`?

Comment: It doesn't, but `Double` does.

Comment: Comparing floating point values using == is indeed dangerous.  Don't do it.

Comment: @ncmathsadist any suggestions?

Comment: You need a closeEnough() method for comparing doubles. What is your error tolerance.  Belly up to the bar and say so.

Comment: @ncmathsadist: Comparing floating-point values with `==` has well-defined, easily-understood semantics.  It is not "dangerous."

Comment: @tmyklebu But there a very few cases where == on doubles really makes sense. Often it is a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained by [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) for `Double`.

> If d1 represents +0.0 while d2 represents -0.0, or vice versa, the equal test has the value false, even though +0.0==-0.0 has the value true.

So a `Double` created from `0.0` is *not* the same as a `Double` created from `-0.0`. The same is not true when you use `0` and `-0` because integers use twos-complement, which has no notion of negative zero. `-0` is the same as `0`. `double`s, on the other hand, [use the IEEE standard for floating point values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), which does recognize a negative zero value.

This behavior is all fixed, so there's no way to have a `HashSet` treat `0.0` and `-0.0` as the same. If you want to do that, you'll need to manually convert all negative zero values into positive zeros before adding or searching for them.

Answer (score 2):

`-0.0` is a literal for a `double` value that is distinct from `0.0`.

`-0` is the negation operator applied to the `int` value `0`, which gives just the `int` value `0`.

Therefore, `new Double(-0)` is equivalent to `new Double(0)`, whereas `new Double(-0.0)` and `new Double(0.0)` actually produce two non-equal `Double` objects.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6724031/3973077) for some explanations for why it is necessary to have two different floating point zero values.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in Wikipedia (thanks), the IEEE format for floating point actually supports negative and positive zeros for various reasons. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

The reason why you find the 0.0 and -0.0 different in your hashmap is directly derived from the IEEE representation. The Double#hashCode method uses the raw bits of the floating point number to calculate the hashcode. Since 0.0 and -0.0 and possibly even +0.0 are different in terms of bits, as some numerical calculations obviously require this, their bits are different and therefore the hashcodes.