# Java If a number is -0

Tags: java, trigonometry

If have this code:

```
double sin = Math.sin(angle*rad);
double cos = Math.cos(angle*rad);
double tan = Math.tan(angle*rad);
```

It returns the triangle function for a specified angle. However for degrees of angle, like 90, -0.00000 is returned. So when these values are printed out, -0 just looks weird. How would -0 be tested for in an if statement?

I have tried with this code:

```
if (tan==0) { s.o.p(tan); }
```

and it doesn't run.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but see https://stackoverflow.com/q/6724031/2422776

Comment: Where do you get this `-0.00000`? I get `-1.2246467991473532E-16` which is close to 0 but not exactly.

Comment: Sorry, tan(180°) has -0.0000, and cos(270.0°) has -0.0000

Comment: Heres the full code: https://pastebin.com/HMU75gKy

Comment: OK, you see -0.0000 because you're formating the result. The result of `System.out.println(Math.tan(Math.PI)); ` is `-1.2246467991473532E-16`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081827/how-to-compare-two-double-values-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the absolute value on the variable when you compare it with zero. You will likely need to cover a range since it's not always likely to be exactly 0.0.

```
if (Math.abs(tan) <= threshold) { ... }
```

Where you set `threshold` to a small enough value to cover what you consider is close enough to 0.

**Edit**: *Added threshold/epsilon value in comparison - thanks [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52834543/java-if-a-number-is-0/52834591#comment92585785_52834591)*

Comment: Which will probably not work because it's not exactly 0 but in a small range around 0. So you probably rather want to define an epsilon so that `Math.abs(tan) < epsilon`

Comment: @Ben Good call, I've added it to my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for negative zero by dividing 1 by your value. This will yield `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` for a positive zero and `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` for a negative zero:

```
if (1.0 / value == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) {
    // Value was a negative zero
}
```