# Dividing 0.0 by -1.0

Tags: java, double

Why does java return a -0.0 when you divide 0.0 by -1. It just seems very strange that the definition of negative numbers is broken when you do the above in Java. A negative number is something that is less than 0. So how can you denote 0.0 as negative.

Comment: Please share your code snippet

Comment: What you see as 0.0 may not be zero exactly but a very small number.

Comment: Actually, in mathematics `-0` and `0` are not equal. `-0 = [x->-infinite] 1/x`, which makes it a negative number. But in java, it shouldn't change anything.

Comment: @Paul Lemarchand  in Java `0 = -0 = -0.0 = +0` please don't misinterpret things

Comment: @ShivCKushawah (that's what I said at the end of my comment)

Comment: @Paul Lemarchand in your first line what is is just contrary that's why I thought that way. Btw good.

Answer (score 3):

Floats are calculated according IEEE-754.
This standard includes positive and negative zero, NaN(Not a Number) and positive/negative infinity.

You can access these special numbers using constants(like `Double.NEGATIVE_ZERO`).

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8153449/823393) for some details but essentially

> `-0.0` represents the result of a rounding to zero of numbers in the range between zero and the smallest representable non-zero negative number.

Some interesting background reading [here](https://blog.csdn.net/jierui001/article/details/3278382).

Comment: Why not close as duplicate instead of answering with a link to an already existing answer?

Comment: @Oleg Because that question is about printing `-0.0`.

Comment: This question: "So how can you denote 0.0 as negative". The other question: "How can a primitive float value be -0.0" seems the same to me. Even if it isn't such a long time and high rep user as yourself should be well aware that the answer is what's important. "As long as an existing answer provides the solution to the general problem and can easily be adapted to the OP's specific situation, it is a duplicate." https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312160/1398418